# Is there a maximum swap partition size for 12.04, 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, ram, swap, memory-usage

I am running 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 on HP Envy Spectre ultrabook, with 4GB of RAM. I have been running into problems with python code which uses RAM very inefficiently, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218601/memory-usage-in-creating-python-dict-from-xml-using-pattern), causing my code to crash. I have increased the swap partition to 8 GB, but crashes still happen. How far can I take it with resizing my swap? 16 GB? 32 GB? At which point will ubuntu be unable to handle it?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a problem with the RAM. Have you tested your RAM?

Comment: Yes, I do run the memory test occasionally, not found any problems. Are there any other tests I could run?

Comment: Which tests have you ran?  If you haven't, you can try [Memory Check](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-server-memory-check.html).

Comment: I occasionally run the built-in memtest86 during boot up, it finds no problems. I also tried the dd/md5 checksum method from your link -all checksums agreed. Also checked memester: no problems, although I am unsure how far I should push it. It doesn't find any problem in tests with up to 2 GB chunks. I guess it's safe to conclude it's not the RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it really matters.  However, if you're using multiple memory intensive applications, you can allocate as big a partition as you want for swap.  How much will be used is another question entirely. Depends on the system.

Personally I don't see any need for a swap partition size larger than twice the amount of ram, not to exceed 8GB.  Having such a huge swap, the swapping process will be probably much less effective.